# Why are entries not deleted?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why MySQL not deleted entries by this query?

```
DELETE FROM transport_cms.page WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT g.Id FROM transport_cms.page g, transport_cms.page p where g.Url = p.Url and g.Site_id = p.Site_id and g.Id != p.Id group by p.Site_id) AS p);
```

Comment: What does it tell you the reason is when you run the query? Do you simply need to run `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` first and then run your delete statement with subquery, etc.?

Comment: You query is not correct. Provide the proper question to fix the issue

Comment: I want to delete dublicate entries in table transport_cms.page. Dublicate - are when Url field is equal, Site_id field is equal, but Id is not equal.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.Id FROM transport_cms.page g, transport_cms.page p where g.Url = p.Url and g.Site_id = p.Site_id and g.Id != p.Id group by p.Site_id
```

This script is not valid. 
The `select` can not contain a field that is not in the `group`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does partially work:-

```
drop table if exists transport_cms_page;

create table transport_cms_page (id int,url varchar(3),site_id int);

insert into transport_cms_page values
(1,'aaa',1),(2,'aaa',1), (3,'aaa',1);

MariaDB [sandbox]> DELETE FROM transport_cms_page
    -> WHERE Id IN (
    -> SELECT * FROM (
    -> SELECT g.Id
    -> FROM transport_cms_page g, transport_cms_page p
    -> where g.Url = p.Url and g.Site_id = p.Site_id and p.Id <> g.Id
    -> group by p.Site_id
    -> ) AS p
    -> );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from transport_cms_page;
+------+------+---------+
| id   | url  | site_id |
+------+------+---------+
|    1 | aaa  |       1 |
|    3 | aaa  |       1 |
+------+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This might be more suitable

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> DELETE FROM transport_cms_page
    -> WHERE Id not IN
    -> (
    -> select minid
    -> from
    -> (select url,site_id, min(id) minid
    -> from transport_cms_page
    -> group by url,site_id
    -> ) m
    -> );
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from transport_cms_page;
+------+------+---------+
| id   | url  | site_id |
+------+------+---------+
|    1 | aaa  |       1 |
+------+------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```